# How to change text button with toggle

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<input id="selectAllButton" type="button" value="Select All">
<script>


$('#selectAllButton').clicktoggle(function(){
    $('#selectAllButton').val('Select None');

  });

</script>
```

i need to change text button between tow option(Select All, Select None) when i click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.val( fn )` as in the demo below:

```js
  $('#selectAllButton').click(function() {
      $(this).val( function() {
         return this.value == 'Select All' ? 'Select None' : 'Select All';
      } );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selectAllButton" type="button" value="Select All">
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#selectAllButton').click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Select All') { $(this).val('Select None'); }
    else { $(this).val('Select All'); }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selectAllButton" type="button" value="Select All">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to change the text, you can use the following code.

```
var selectButton = $('#selectAllButton');
selectButton.click(function(){
    selectButton.val(selectButton.val() == 'Select None' ? 'Select All' : 'Select None');
});
```